# C# Async GetWebRequest failing to POST data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono, httpwebrequest, streamwriter

I recently wrote an async HttpWebRequest client for our application and it works fine in .NET 3.5, but on Mono it fails to correctly write the data on to the request before sending it out.

I have confirmed the problem using wireshark to sniff the outgoing packets. The HTTP request is correctly set to POST with a JSON Content Type however the Content-Length and data are 0.

I currently get one exception:

> The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified
>   ContentLength.

I have tried to resolve this by manually setting the ContentLength of the WebRequest and changing the way I encode the data before giving it to the stream (I have tried both a Steam and StreamWriter).

I have also stepped through the code and debug logged the variables in the async method to ensure the data is really there. It just does not appear to be getting to the WebRequest object.

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void StartWebRequest(string payload) {
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PortMapSleuthURL);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Proxy = null; // Setting this to null will save some time.

    // start an asynchronous request:
    httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback, new object[] {httpWebRequest, payload});

    try {
        // Send the request and response callback:
        httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(FinishPortTestWebRequest, httpWebRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        PortTestException();
    }
}

private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
    try {
        object[] args = (object[])asyncResult.AsyncState;

        string payload = (string)args[1];
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)args[0];

        //StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult), new UTF8Encoding(false));
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult), Encoding.UTF8);

        // Write to the request stream.
        streamWriter.Write(payload);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        PortTestException();
    }
}
```

Comment: a difference like this between mono and .NET is considered a bug; what version of mono are you using?

Comment: Its running in the Unity3D Mono fork. Looks like its Mono 2.12: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are supposed to call `BeginGetResponse` before `EndGetRequestStream`. That is, I would move that into the `GetRequestStreamCallback`. This is how the [example on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx) works too.